# Qt5 font rendering in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: fonts, 13.04, qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-sdk

My fonts in general within QtCreator inside Ubuntu 13.04 looks 'ugly' when compared to how they looked in 12.10.

12.10 still used Qt4, so did something regarding the font rendering in Qt5 and the most up to date QtCreator change then?

If so, is there a workaround and or fix for this please? Seeing that this affects the Ubuntu-SDK (which of course is using QtCreator) one would assume that a fix must be available ;)

Comment: The fonts go back to pretty if you use MainView instead of Rectangle as the root element, at least for me.  Check the Ubuntu-touch style guide for details about the font styles and recommendations on which ones to use where.

Answer (score 1):

By default qt5 used xft instead of fontconfig how it was in qt4 version: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27106. Infinality patch is fix that for me.

- Install infinality font patch:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa 
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality`
- Configure font config:

  `sudo bash /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle`
  and select `linux`
- In file `/etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh` change variable USE_STYLE from DEFAULT to UBUNTU: `USE_STYLE="UBUNTU"` (in my PC it's line #712)
- Restart X server.

For more information see http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html. I tested that on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qt5 Configuration Tool](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt5+Configuration+Tool?content=168066) to tell Qt 5 to use GTK+ style and change font settings

[image]