# Font rendering problems with QT applications in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, gtk, qt

I'm currently using Xubuntu 14.04 but the same problem is present in 13.10 and 13.04, and maybe in previous versions.

I always install truetype fonts and remove the anti-alias. In all the GTK applications the fonts look perfect, but in Qt applications like Scribus of Calibre the fonts have render problems. I included a image where you have an screen capture of a GTK application and a Qt application together. Underlined in red is the word "Editar". Look at how the "a" and the "r" are together in the Qt application (right side). I already installed `qtcurve` and adjusted the settings but nothing happens. Also followed the guide here (http://mikemcquaid.com/2011/12/01/make-qt-use-the-gtk-style-on-xfce-or-xubuntu/) and nothing happens.

Here is the image: GTK and Qt applications side by side

[image: GTK and Qt applications side by side]

Xangua, Thanks for your help. I already tried using QT configuration but it didn't work. I included an image of how the fonts look on Qt applications. As you can see in the image, sometimes the letters "join".

[image: Screen capture Qt application under Xubuntu]

Comment: I found solution for version 14.04, but it seem works on ubuntu 13.04 version too:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/285862/qt5-font-rendering-in-ubuntu-13-04/569313#569313

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `qt4-qtconfig` to be able to change qt applications style and fonts. I just set it to emulate the gtk engine. I never had issues at least in Gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

To enable this style, use:

```
Qt Configuration: choose "GTK+" under Appearance > GUI Style.
The command-line: edit the ~/.config/Trolltech.conf file by adding:

~/.config/Trolltech.conf
...
[Qt]
style=GTK+
...
```

[image]

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_Qt_and_GTK_Applications

Comment: Do either of these fixes, installing qt4-config or editing Trolltech.conf, work with `qt5` apps?

Comment: @DKBose For Qt5 applications, you would use `qt5ct`: install with `sudo apt install qt5ct`, start with `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct qt5ct`.