# How to make Qt apps use GTK+ style in Xubuntu 15.04?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 right now, and Qt apps like qBittorrent and Clementine looks like they were GTK+ apps, they use the systems icons and style.
But I installed Xubuntu in another PC and doesn't happens the same. Qt apps doesn't look good and doesn't use the system's style.

I tried [this](http://mikemcquaid.com/2011/12/01/make-qt-use-the-gtk-style-on-xfce-or-xubuntu/) but it doesn't work, I don't know if this fix is obsolete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font rendering problems with QT applications in Xubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461182/font-rendering-problems-with-qt-applications-in-xubuntu)

Comment: You should check my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/461182/font-rendering-problems-with-qt-applications-in-xubuntu

Comment: It looks better, but it doesn't use GTK+ icons.